# A Banach Space cannot have a denumerable basis:Why is it true?

Tags: functional-analysis

I came across the following theorem:

**A Banach Space cannot have a denumerable basis** which has been proven in my book.

I can't understand why is it true since $\mathbb R$ is a banach space over $\mathbb R$ and it has a countable basis i.e $\{1\}$

Where am I missing the link?

Comment: If your book proves this, which step of the proof fails in the case of $\mathbb R$? Could the statement really say "cannot have a *countably infinite* base"?

Comment: interior of  a proper subspace of a nls is empty: which is false in R @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: The only *proper* subspace of $\mathbb R$ is $0$ and has empty interior ...

Comment: yes sorry ;you are right @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: this is the only fact used and Baire Category theirem ;so where am i missing @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: See $\,$ [B.V.Limaye _Functional Analysis_ (1996)](https://books.google.it/books?id=BaEgbIoPTygC&pg=PA132&dq=A+Banach+Space+cannot+have+a+denumerable+basis&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAWoVChMIjqek_JPGxwIVw1oUCh0YGAqZ#v=onepage&q=A%20Banach%20Space%20cannot%20have%20a%20denumerable%20basis&f=false),$\,$Th. 8.4, p. 132 .

Comment: Ok, denumerable = countably infinite. Then it is true.

Comment: @DavidMitra I also wrote this comment, but then google that denumerable means *precisely* cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$. A finite basis is then not denumerable, so the claim is true for *any* Banach space.

Comment: Suppose that $ E $ is a  Banach space of infinite dimension and  has a countable basis $ (e_n)_{n\in \mathbb N} $ for $ n \in \mathbb {N} $.

Then define $F_n $ , vector space generated by  $e_i $  for $ i \leq n $.

As $  F_n$  is of finite dimensional  then  it is a closed  space  with  empty interior. But the union of $F_n $  is equals to  $ E $.  Thanks to Baire's theorem,  $ E $  should be empty interior  which is absurd.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose that $\{e_1,e_2,...\}$ is a basis of the Banach spaces $M$. Let $M_n=\text{span}\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$. So $M_n$ is closed, and is a proper subspace of $M$. So $\text{int}(M_n)=\emptyset$. Given $x\in M$, since $\{e_1,e_2,...\}$ is a Hamel basis of $M$ there exists $n$ such that $x=\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_je_j$, so $x\in M_n$. This prove that $M=\bigcup_nM_n$. Then $M$ is a countable union of sets with empty interior, by Baire's theorem $M$ needs to satisfy $\text{int}(M) \neq \emptyset$, contradiction.

Note: $\text{int}(M)$ is the interior of $M$.

Answer (score 5):

Of course every finite dimensional Banach space has a finite basis. As a consequence of Baires category theorem every infintedimensional Banach space cannot have a countable Hamel Basis, but very often a Schauder basis.There exist separable Banach spaces that don´t even have a Schauder basis so as was shown by Per Enflo. So You are right, the word "infinitedimensional" is missing in the statement