# Vector space isomorphism and cardinalities

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, cardinals

Let $V=\{(a_1,a_2,...,a_n,0,0,...)|n\in \mathbb{N}, a_i\in \mathbb{R}\}$ be the vector space of eventually zero sequences in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ with addition and scalar multiplication point-wise. I am trying to show that this is $not$ isomorphic to the vector space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$. One approach I tried was to compare cardinalities. So I calculated

$$|V|=\aleph_1+\aleph_1^2+\aleph_1^3+...=\aleph_1+\aleph_1+\aleph_1+...=\aleph_1*\aleph_0=\aleph_1$$
and
$$|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}|=\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}$$

So I am wondering whether it is known whether or not $$\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_1$$

Comment: As Asaf Karagila wrote, the notion of *dimension* (over $\mathbb{R}$) is crucial here. Two vector spaces over some field are isomorphic iff they have the same dimension over said field. The dimension of a vector space may not be easy to compute however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. $\Bbb R$ is a set of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, which may or may not be equal to $\aleph_1$.
2. $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$.

The first one is in fact the continuum hypothesis and the fact it is neither provable nor disprovable from the axioms of $\sf ZFC$ requires a lot of technical work. The latter can be proved using simple cardinal arithmetic and the Cantor–Bernstein theorem.

---

Comparing cardinalities won't do you much good here. But you can prove that exactly one of these spaces has a countable dimension. (See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131711/vector-space-of-infinite-sequences-in-bbb-r/2131754#2131754) for more details.)