# Why in infinite dimension $\text{Span}\{e_i^*\}\subsetneq E^*$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Q1) Let $E$ a vector space of infinite dimension. Let $\{e_i\}_{i\in\mathcal I}$ a basis of $E$. Why $$\text{Span}\{e_i^*\}_{i\in \mathcal I}\subsetneq E^*$$ 
where $E^*$ is the algebraic dual. (Notice that I know that $\{e_i^*\}_{i\in\mathcal I}$ is linearly independent in $E^*$).

Q2) Suppose now $E$ is a normed space (with $\{e_i\}_{i\in\mathcal I}$ a basis). If $E'$ is the topological dual, will we have $$\text{Span}\{e_i^*\}_{i\in\mathcal I}=E' \ \ ?$$

Q3) Why the topological dual is strictly included in the algebraic dual ? I can find linear application $E\to E$ that are not continuous, but I have difficulties to describe a linear form that is not continuous.

Answer (score 3):

1) It is not so hard to construct an $f \in E^* \setminus \operatorname{span}\{e_i^*\}_{i \in I}$. To do this, notice it is enough to define $f(e_i) = 1$ for each $i$ and extend by linearity. Then if $f = \sum_{j} a_j e_j^*$ then $f(e_i) = 1$ implies that $\alpha_i = 1$. But if $f \in \operatorname{span}\{e_i^*\}_{i \in I}$ then all but finitely many of the $\alpha_j$ are $0$ so we see that $f \not \in \operatorname{span}\{e_i^*\}_{i \in I}$.

2) In general, no. For example, let $c_0$ be the space of sequences with finitely many non-zero entries equipped with the supremum norm. Then $c_0 = \operatorname{span}\{e_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $e_i$ is the sequence with $1$ in the $i$-th place and $0$ elsewhere. It is well known that $c_0' \simeq \ell^1$. However we cannot have $\ell^1 = \operatorname{span}\{e_i^*\}$ because $\ell^1$ is a Banach space and hence cannot have a countable basis (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1409963/256128)).

3) Doing this for an arbitrary vector space relies on the axiom of choice (or more precisely the assumption you can find a basis). Let $X$ be your infinite dimensional normed space and suppose $\{e_i: i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a linearly independent set such that $\|e_i\| = 1$. Extend it to a basis $\{e_i: i \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{d_i: i \in I\}$ for $X$. Then define $f(e_i) = i$ and $f(d_i) = 0$ and extend $f$ by linearity to all of $X$ so that $f \in X^*$. Since $f(e_i) = i$, $f \not \in X'$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer. Just one question : does 
$Span \{e_i^* \}_{i\in \mathcal I}=E^{'}$ can hold ?